# How to get list of all elements from a 'Disjoint Sets'

Tags: c++, boost, disjoint-sets

In my problem, I have a bunch of Elements (Class Element). Say I have 1000 Elements. These Elements are initially un-associated which means they are in their own sets.

Later I need to use the union operation to merge some of these sets based of my program flow. 
I plan to use the boost library's disjoint_set (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html)

My question is how is it possible to list the Elements in a set given the representative of the set.

Is disjoint_set the best data structure for such a task. So should I look into using something else?

Comment: After looking at the (new for me) disjoint_set_* classes, I don't think that they afford iterating members of sets. They act like unidirectional mapping from element to set representative. In case it helps you: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8881626/

Answer (score 0):

From your prose description, I get no information that the sets would actually form any graphs.

If all you want to do is associate Elements with a set, I'd suggest

```
std::map<ElementId, SetId>
```

(where `ElementId` could simply be `Element*` if you know the pointers stay valid).

If you also want to be able to query the inverse efficiently

```
bimap<Element, bimaps::multiset_of<SetId> >
```

would be a candidate. See a demonstration <strike>**Live On Coliru**</strike>¹

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    using Element = int; // for simplicity :)
    using SetId   = int;
    using Sets = bimap<Element, bimaps::multiset_of<SetId> >;

    Sets sets;
    sets.insert({ Element(1), 300 });
    sets.insert({ Element(2), 300 });
    sets.insert({ Element(3), 400 });
    sets.insert({ Element(4), 300 });

    // give us set #300
    for (auto& e : make_iterator_range(sets.right.equal_range(300)))
        std::cout << e.first << " - Element(" << e.second << ")\n";
}
```

Prints

```
300 - Element(1)
300 - Element(2)
300 - Element(4)
```

---

¹ Coliru seems down. Will add later